# DataGrid CharacterCasing Upper bug

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, wpfdatagrid

I applied style setter "CharacterCasing" with value="Upper" to a textcolumn of a wpf datagrid, if I double click on a cell and start typing everything works fine.
But the problem is when I single click on a cell and start typing, the first letter is small and rest uppercase.

How do I fix it? Can I enable editing on cells only user double clicks and not on single click?

Comment: This is quite similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7890922/199220). Check there for a workaround.